# More Messages In Azure Service Bus Queue than sent

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure-servicebus-queues

In an attempt to catch and retry transient exceptions when sending to a queue in an azure service bus, I am seeing more messages than sent when sending more than 25,000 messages in a test scenario.  I expected that if I did have excess messages, they would be the result of some sort of timeout/retry that actually had reached the message bus the first time.

**We are using the .Net Standard Micrososft.Azure.ServiceBus library version 3.0.2**

The basic logic in an infinite loop:

1. await sending message to queue
2. break if successful
3. catch exception and test if it is a transient one that benefits from retry
4. wait random time from 1-3 seconds and retry
5. any not caught exception is logged by the caller.

Other notes - in debug, I see many "system.timeout" exceptions, but can't catch them when not running in debug.

```
  public async Task SendToAzureQueue(Message messageToSend) {

        while (true) {
            try {                    
                await messageSender.SendAsync(messageToSend);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (
                ex is ServerBusyException ||
                ex is ServiceBusCommunicationException ||
                ex is ServiceBusTimeoutException ||
                ex is SessionCannotBeLockedException ||
                ex is SocketException
            ) {
                _logger.Warn($"Transient Exception Thrown. MessageId: {messageToSend.MessageId} - Retrying in 1-10 seconds.\n", ex);
                var randomGenerator = new Random();
                await Task.Delay(randomGenerator.Next(1000, 10000));
            }                
        }
    }
```

The calling function wraps this with a try/catch (exception)

Here is the code of the integration test that calls the above code:

```
var graphLogObjects = AutoFixture.CreateMany<GraphlogWithNumericId>(30000);

var tasks = graphLogObjects
            .Select(graphLogEntryDto => _jsonSerializer.Serialize(graphLogEntryDto))
            .Select(dataToSend => graphLogMessageQueue.SendToAzureQueue(Message messageToSend));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Are send and receive operation concurrent or not? What's the recieve processing logic looks like and how long does it take to complete a message? How do you recieve your messages, using OnMessage API/message handler or receiving manually? If manually, do you receive in batches? Is there a prefetch configured? etc, etc, etc. It would be really helpful to see your code and not just a snippet for sending a single messages. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanFeldman - Yes, the sending logic is concurrent.  I will post the logic shortly. As for receiving, that is a separate service that is turned off.  I am just looking (with queue explorer) at the counts after running a test that creates 30,000 messages and sends them in concurrently.  When changed to synchronous, the number is 30,000.  I suspect a timeout occurs and is automatically resent even though the queue already got it.

Comment: @SeanFeldman - it takes a fraction of a second to send the message.  I haven't put timers around it, but that definitely contributes to the problem.  When I send the same number of integers, the correct number of integers arrive in the queue.

Comment: do you get any exceptions logged in the SendToAzureQueue() method? Also, what ASB client and version are you using?

Comment: @SeanFeldman - MessageSender in "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" version 3.0.2 - There is not exception caught/logged in the SendToAzureQueue() method.  Even a "catch all" around the entire method does not log any errors.  When I watch the test in Debug - I see a System.Timeout exception.  I am not resubmitting those though.  If they are getting submitted more than once - could it be some auto retry in the sender?

Comment: `MessageSender` retries if there's a failure to get an acknowledgement from the broker. I would consider it a bug if there was no acknowledgement, but message stored on the service. Any chance you could share a GitHub project with the repro? I'll run it locally as well.